# how to use template in vue3 instead of native template?

Tags: vue.js

I'm tring to make a SelectBox component

```js
<Options>
  <Option
    v-for="person in people"
    :value="person"
  >
    {{ person.name }}
  </Option>
</Options>
```

And I want `Option` to be a dynamic component:

```js
<component :is="props.as || 'li'">
  <slot />
</component>
```

So I can custom content in `Option` (not only with `<li>` tag), for example use `div` or `template` to render

```js
<Options>
  <Option
    v-for="person in people"
    :value="person"
    as="template"
  >
    <li>
      <span>{{ person.name }}</span>
      <span>other</span>
    </li>
  </Option>
</Options>
```

But if prop.as is 'template', it's rendered in html native template and can't see it in browser
[image]

I expect the result:
[image]

Vue document show some detail
[image]

But it can't work for me to add any director on it, like this

```js
<component
  :is="props.as || 'li'"
  v-if="true"
>
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't be using the `component` tag for what you're trying to do.

According to the [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-elements.html#component), here are the options of what you can pass for the `is` prop:

> The actual component to render is determined by the `is` prop.
>
> - When `is` is a string, it could be either an HTML tag name or a component's registered name.
> - Alternatively, `is` can also be directly bound to the definition of a component.

You are trying to pass a `template` instead of a Vue component, which `component` is not designed to work with. It is unclear exactly what you are trying to do, but you can probably use a `slot` to accomplish it. Otherwise, to get the `component` tag working, define a Vue component and pass that in.

Comment: I update my post and explain what I'm trying to do. `slot` cannot accomplish it. I would appreciate it If you had any other solution.

Comment: Thanks man! I know how to accomplish it